# "a baseball game" vs. "a game of baseball"

Tags: word-usage, collocations

From Cambridge Dictionary:  [a game of baseball](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/game).

I understand its meaning and usage. For example, I can construct a sentence with it.

> How long does a game of baseball last

When I put the sentence on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20long%20does%20a%20game%20of%20baseball%20last&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=how%20long%20a%20game%20of%20baseball%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l7.6028j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), most of the results I got use **a baseball game**.

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=a%20game%20of%20baseball%2C%20a%20baseball%20game&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20game%20of%20baseball%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20baseball%20game%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20game%20of%20baseball%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20baseball%20game%3B%2Cc0) also shows the latter is more common than the former

[image]

Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: I'd argue there's a difference, resulting from their respective emphasis: You _play_ a "game of baseball" (the game itself) and _attend_ a "baseball game" (the experience of being at a venue full of baseball fans). You can _watch_ either one, but your choice says something about how much attention you're paying.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you: Yes, but as your distinction is stylistic, not grammatical or lexical, it may not be helpful with respect to the difficulty that prompted the question.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you: But I accept the objection that the reasons why "baseball game" is more common may not be limited to its length.

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing, but as the-baby-is-blue says, "baseball game" is the normal choice if you are watching a game (for example, "we went to the baseball game last Saturday"). (See [baseball game](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/baseball+game) at The Free Dictionary.)